# calculating marginal tax rates

Tags: r

I found part of the answer to my problem of calculating marginal taxes using this:

```
income_tax <- 
function(income,
         brackets = c(18200, 37000, 80000, 180000, Inf),
         rates = c(0, .19, .325, .37, .45)) {        
    sum(diff(c(0, pmin(income, brackets))) * rates)
}
```

I want to also be able to calculate a fixed component so that i can add say $100 to the tax calculated for every income above the first bracket of 18200.

I tried this but it adds $100 to all incomes below 18200 as well.

```
income_tax <- 
function(income,
         brackets = c(18200, 37000, 80000, 180000, Inf),
         rates = c(0, .19, .325, .37, .45),
         fixed = c(0,100,0,0,0)) {        
    sum(diff(c(0, pmin(income, brackets))) * rates + pmin(income, fixed))
}
```

any help on whatever obvious error i've made would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
income_tax <- function(income,
                       brackets = c(18200, 37000, 80000, 180000, Inf),
                       rates = c(0, .19, .325, .37, .45),
                       fixed = c(0,100,0,0,0)) { 
       
                       check <- diff(c(0,pmin(income, brackets)))       
                       sum(check * rates + fixed * (check>0)) }
```

which gives,

```
income_tax(18200)
# [1] 0
income_tax(18201)
#[1] 100.19
```